# Python exception when calculating age

Tags: python, exception

I have a python code that ask user input for the date of birth and returns the age of the user. However, I'd like to modify the code so if the user input enter the date with the wrong format a message is shown so the user can try again. I am aware that there is the while loop for this type of tasks, but haven't been able to make it work.

```
import datetime as date

def calculateAge(birthDate): 
    today = date.datetime.today() 
    age = today.year - birthDate.year -((today.month, today.day) < (birthDate.month, birthDate.day))
    return age 

birthDate = input("Please enter your birthdate on the following format (dd/mm/yyyy)\n>>> ")
birthDate = date.datetime.strptime(birthDate, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
print("Your birthday is on "+ birthDate.strftime("%d") + " of " + birthDate.strftime("%B, %Y"))

#lets print the age now
 print("You are", calculateAge(birthDate), "years old")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
birthDate = input("Please enter your birthdate on the following format (dd/mm/yyyy)\n>>> ")
while True:
    try:
        birthDate = date.datetime.strptime(birthDate, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
        break
    except(ValueError):
        birthDate = input("Please enter your birthdate on the following format (dd/mm/yyyy)\n>>> ")
```

`try` attempts to do the function under try, which is to convert into a date. If it is in the correct format, then it will exit the while loop. However, if its in the wrong format, then it will raise a `ValueError` and thats what `except` catches and it will ask for the input again. This will continue till it exits the while loop only through keying in something in the proper format.